# Javascript event listener doesn't update boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a very basic javascript game using the html5 canvas. So, I created a main player "class" which is supposed to create a red circle on the canvas upon instantiating and invoking the "init method". Lastly, its also supposed to be controllable via the arrow keys and to do that, I tried to add event listeners to the document, checking for keydown/keyup which would then change boolean values like leftPressed = true; etc. Based on that, the displace method(called in the setInterval function draw) was meant to update the location of the red circle and therein lies my problem - upon opening the index.html file, the red circle is created, but when I hit the arrow keys, I cannot get it to move. Any help would be appreciated and please excuse my ignorance, I started javascript about a week ago.

Here is the js code containing the player "class":

```
canvas = document.getElementById("surface");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//user controlled player class

player = function(x,y,dx,dy,radius) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedx = dx;
    this.speedy = dy;
    this.radius = radius;

    this.leftPressed = false;
    this.rightPressed = false;
    this.upPressed = false;
    this.downPressed = false;

    document.addEventListener("keydown",this.onKeyDown,false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup",this.onKeyUp,false);


    this.init = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    this.onKeyDown = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            this.leftPressed = true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            this.upPressed = true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            this.rightPressed = true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            this.downPressed = true;
        }
    }
    this.onKeyUp = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            this.leftPressed = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            this.upPressed = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            this.rightPressed = false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            this.downPressed = false;
        }
    }
    this.displace = function() {
        if (this.leftPressed) {
            this.x -= this.speedx;
        }
        if (this.rightPressed) {
            this.x += this.speedx;
        }
        if (this.downPressed) {
            this.y -= this.speedy;
        }
        if (this.upPressed) {
            this.y += this.speedy;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the main.js code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("surface");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);



player1 = new player(500,500,7,7,25);


function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    player1.init();
    player1.displace();
}

setInterval(draw,10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classic Javascript bug: the `this` keyword doesn't act like you might expect.

In this code:

```
function C() {
    this.prop = true;
    this.get = function() {
        return this.prop;
    }
}
var obj = new C();
```

`obj.get()` will return `true`, but `var get = obj.get; get()` will return `undefined`. The exact explanation as to why is a bit nuts-and-bolts to get into here, but in general, the simplest answer is **do not reference member functions to execute later**. Instead, do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    this.onKeyDown(e);
}, false);
```

This works because the lambda syntax doesn't mess with `this`. If you want to support pre-lambda JS, you can do this slightly uglier version:

```
var self = this;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    self.onKeyDown(e);
}, false);
```

or use `bind` to fix it.

In short, there are many solutions to this but to understand all of them you need a good understanding of Javascript's slightly quirky protoptypical inheritance system.

Comment: The lambda syntax worked flawlessly. Tnx a lot, I've been so annoyed by this problem as the developer console didn't show any errors. I was wondering if you could point me towards a learning resource for JS that covers things like these(lambda). For the most part, I just watched video tutorials that only explained the absolute basics. Again, tnx a lot!

Comment: I don't really know of an up-to-date JS resource, sorry. But yeah, the console wouldn't show an error for this because `this` still refers to _something_ and the callback was quite successfully adding a `leftPressed` flag to whatever that thing was. It just wasn't where your code was looking for it.